# Best way to structure this Firebase Collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a study app where users can: add a new task name, create a study session which will contain task name, startime, duration.
Later I need the following information: Todays total study time, a List of each study session todays total study time for each task name for the day, month,year. I will have a calendar that will Show a list of all study session the day it will be clicked.

I was considering using sub collections like this:

```
 StudySessions Collection:
 - Document (User ID):
   - Subcollection "Sessions":
     - Document (Session ID):
       - Task: "Math"
       - StartTime: Timestamp
       - EndTime: Timestamp
       - ...
   - Subcollection "Statistics":
     - Document "Daily":
       - Date: Timestamp (Use the date as the document ID)
       - TotalStudyTime: Duration
       - TaskTotals: Map<String, Duration> (Task name as keys, total study time as values)
     - Document "Monthly":
       - Year: Number
       - Month: Number
       - TotalStudyTime: Duration
       - TaskTotals: Map<String, Duration> (Task name as keys, total study time as values)
```

Bu then I realized in need the user to have clickable task name buttons so they dont have to reenter it every time they create a new study session and for this I need a separate collection, but then I also need the user to be able to delete a task name from the list of task names without deleting every single record associated with that task name (only deleting it from the list of clickable task names when creating a new study session), what would be the best way to structure this taking into account performance since I am relatively new to programming. kind regards

Comment: What's wrong with the actual structure?

Comment: I was wondering how to make it better for performance since I am a beginner

Comment: What issues regarding performance are you experiencing right now? What exactly would you like to improve?

Comment: In NoSQL you model the data for the use-cases you have. So if you're stuck on a current use-case, please show us the code that isn't working (or working too slowly). If you're looking for more general data modeling advice, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)